# Qual è il significato di "rimbaldino"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> 1943. Lo stato di guerra cominciò a scozzonare il nostro gruppo. Primo a partire fu uno degli amici non attori, Umberto, fiera natura di giramondo, striata di profumi **rimbaldini**. Partì infatti quasi contento, per il fronte africano, dove fu subito fatto prigioniero dagli inglesi e trascorse un paio d'anni dietro il filo spinato.

Ho cercato il significato di "rimbaldino", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Si riferisce forse a qualche personaggio di cognome Rimbaldo o Rimbaldi? Sapreste dirmi a quale?

Comment: Sospetto che sia un aggettivo relativo a Rimbaud, ma aspetto conferme.

Comment: https://books.google.it/books?id=ysmZ67cdFKgC&pg=PA460&dq=rimbaldino&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rimbaldino&f=false sembra confermare il sospetto di DaG

Comment: @DaG: E io ho trovato questo: http://www.clarence.com/contents/cultura-spettacolo/societamenti/autorimz/rimbaud/.

Comment: E anche questo: https://books.google.es/books?id=ysmZ67cdFKgC&pg=PA459&lpg=PA459&dq=rimbaud+rimbaldina&source=bl&ots=oYxWUWNVZx&sig=FkIDpO1wUfbg8wqhRT-iQ0kdwTs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi289HS4qfNAhWBuBQKHWv9AiEQ6AEICzAA#v=onepage&q=rimbaud%20rimbaldina&f=false.

Comment: Appare anche qui: http://www.poesia2punto0.com/2013/10/27/generazione-p-con-oroscopo-generazionale/.

Comment: @DaG: Penso che adesso sia chiaro che si tratti di un aggettivo relativo a Rimbaud, ma qualcuno dovrebbe scrivere la risposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per quanto abbiamo potuto ricavare da alcune fonti

- https://books.google.it/books?id=ysmZ67cdFKgC&pg=PA460&dq=rimbaldino&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rimbaldino&f=false
- http://www.clarence.com/contents/cultura-spettacolo/societamenti/autorimz/rimbaud/
- https://books.google.es/books?id=ysmZ67cdFKgC&pg=PA459&lpg=PA459&dq=rimbaud+rimbaldina&source=bl&ots=oYxWUWNVZx&sig=FkIDpO1wUfbg8wqhRT-iQ0kdwTs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi289HS4qfNAhWBuBQKHWv9AiEQ6AEICzAA#v=onepage&q=rimbaud%20rimbaldina&f=false
- http://www.poesia2punto0.com/2013/10/27/generazione-p-con-oroscopo-generazionale/

sembra che sia un aggettivo relativo a Rimbaud.